# Android - How to align a TextView text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following `layout` for a `ListView` item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_icon_image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/m" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Business Name"
        android:id="@+id/item_title_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_icon_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Distance"
        android:id="@+id/item_distance_text"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_title_text"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_icon_image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the rendered result:

[image: item layout]

As you can see there is a gap between the real text and the bottom of the image... I was expecting to have the bottom of the text matching exactly with the bottom of the image...so question is: How can I align the text to the bottom of the image?

(this also happens for the top text, but in the top instead)

---

EDIT:

For now I am using:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
```

But I wanted something more automatic, some solution that won't depend on dp or screen....but as commented, this might be impossible, because the `View` needs to make space for letter such as 'y', 'g' and 'j'....but I wish there could be something that will align it based on it's contents, so if there wasn't a 'g', it won't be saving this space.

Comment: If you change the bottom word to something with y's or g's, it may help you understand why the alignment is not perfect. Otherwise, you can always use `android:layout_marginTop` and `android:layout_marginBottom` to move the text about manually if it is static.

Comment: Well this makes sense for 'y' 'j' 'g'...but still there is a top part that i can completely fill, I tried all the capitalized letters and accents.

Comment: put ImageView and TextView inside a RelativeLayout. Set RelativeLayout height param to wrap_content and then in ImageView and TextView set android:layout_alignParentBottom to true. And do not forget to set android:layout_toLeftOf on TextView with ImageView id.

Comment: @Varundroid doesnt work either :/

Answer (score 1):

You should add `android:gravity="top"` to your top text view and `android:gravity="bottom"` to your bottom text view to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Business Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="odp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_distance_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Distance"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This just pushes things around, I wanted something that wont depend on the screen, something automatic....for now I am using `android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"` which does the same

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this to acheive the desired result:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Distance"
        android:id="@+id/item_distance_text"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_title_text"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_icon_image"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Comment: try to give top margin 5dp

Comment: Yes, that's my current solution....but I wanted something that wont depend on measures

Comment: try to use linear layout with vertical orientation and set weightsum=2 then give weight=1 to every text view to take 50 50 of total height, it won't require your dp!